# Oracle for searching in a sorted list

Tags: quantum-algorithms, oracles

I'm working on the algorithm to search an item in a sorted list based on this article: https://web.mit.edu/rsi/www/pdfs/papers/2003/2003-brianj.pdf

I can't see how to make implement this oracle with Qiskit.

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, to minus sign in the correct/wrong answer, you can make CNOT on $|-\rangle$ state: acting with $X$ on $|-\rangle$ results in $X|-\rangle=-|-\rangle$. ($|-\rangle$ is created using $H|1\rangle$).

So, what you need is $CNOT$ acting on ancilla which is initialized to $|-\rangle$ to be your target.

Because you are looking for a solution that is true only for this range of $x$, you actually want your control of CNOT to be the MSB qubit.

Notice that for $N=4$:

```
Deciaml -> Binary

0 -> 000,
1 -> 001,
..,
3 -> 011,
4 -> 100,
5 -> 101,
...,
7 -> 111
```

So, all the oracle is just adding ancilla that is initialized to $|-\rangle$, and $CNOT$ where the control is $x_0$ (the MSB), and the target is the ancilla.

So, if $x_0$ is your MSB:

```
q[0..(log2(2*N)-1)] is the array of qubits as input
init qA=X|0>=|1> is the ancilla
qA = H(qA) = |->
CNOT(target=qA, control=q[0])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am still a beginner, I did not understand the principle of ancilla. Also, does X stand for Pauli-X Gate ?

Comment: Yes, X is Pauli-X. And ancilla is just one more qubit that is helping your calculations. it is not special, just one more qubit. and |->=(1/sqrt(2))(|0>+|1>)

Comment: @RonCohen $|-\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|0\rangle-|1\rangle\right)$ :p

Comment: Haha didnt notice thanks